# Why fetchedObject count whole entity - not attributes?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I try count number in  (values8 for example) 1 of 100 attributes of Event

And always got that count all number in all property of Event!

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequests = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entit = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:str  inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];
 NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entit propertiesByName];
 [fetchRequests setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
 [fetchRequests setEntity:entit] ;

 [fetchRequests setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:value]]]; 
 NSError *error;
 NSArray *fetchedObject = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequests error:&error];
 NSManagedObject *fetched ;
 NSManagedObject *fetch ;
    printf("\n%d", [fetchedObject count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a predicate. As written you code ask for an array containing the value of a specific attribute for every existing instance of the `Event` entity in the object graph. The count of the array will be the count of all `Event` instances in the object graph. If you want to find specific `Event` instances with specific values you need to provide the fetch a predicate.

See the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html)

If you want to perform operations on the array returned by the fetch see: [Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html)

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:value];

Comment: I thought that setPropertiesToFetch  - locate property that i need. NSPredicate error - Unable to parse the format string "values58"'

Comment: It will locate the property of each instance of the entity but without a predicate it will return one property value for each instances. E.g. if you have 10 Event objects you get an array with ten property values.